# SQL-PL trigger compilation error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create a trigger which will enter values into a table terminated_employees when we delete values from the nm_employees table. I have written the trigger but it I am getting compilation errors for the PL statement. Any ideas?

```
CREATE TABLE nm_departments(
dept2 varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT empPK PRIMARY KEY (dept2)
);

CREATE TABLE nm_employees(
name varchar(20),
dept varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT departments FOREIGN KEY (dept) REFERENCES nm_departments (dept2)ON DELETE     CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE terminated_employees(
te_name varchar(20),
te_dept varchar(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DeleteCustomer
BEFORE DELETE ON nm_employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO terminated_employees (te_name,te_dept)
VALUES(:Old.te_name, :Old.te_dept);
END DeleteCustomer;
```

Comment: which database are you using? which line of code gets the error? what exactly does the error say? (p.s. we are not psychic)

Comment: unless you have billions of employees, I would simply add a column `terminated boolean` to the employee table and leave it at that.

Comment: @Bohemian this looks like Oracle syntax to me—added tag

Comment: In order to select values from a table you have to use the column names of that table, not the column names of the *table you're inserting into* .

Comment: @bohemian - logical deletions are Teh Suck!  regardless of the volume of records involved.

Comment: @APC But they're personnel records - you're likely to want to still want them treated as employees. Just one use case is producing tax reports at the end of the year, even if they're *currently* terminated, you still produce a report if they did some work during the year. There are many other use cases where you want to deal with terminated and current employees similarly. If you move the row, you just end up having to do things twice. Also, you can create a view `current_employees` that has a `where not terminated` to make it fairly painless for app programmers. Nope, I sticking to my guns :)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DeleteCustomer
   BEFORE DELETE ON nm_employees
   FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
   INSERT INTO terminated_employees 
   VALUES(:Old.name, :Old.dept);
   END;
/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will compile, if you are writing trigger on *nm_employees* than this will be the code you have to write

```
 CREATE TABLE nm_departments(
    dept2 varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT empPK PRIMARY KEY (dept2)
    );

CREATE TABLE nm_employees(
name varchar(20),
dept varchar(20),
CONSTRAINT departments FOREIGN KEY (dept) REFERENCES nm_departments (dept2)ON DELETE     CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE terminated_employees(
te_name varchar(20),
te_dept varchar(20)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DeleteCustomer
BEFORE DELETE ON nm_employees
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO terminated_employees (te_name,te_dept)
VALUES(:Old.name, :Old.dept);
END DeleteCustomer;
```